# Is $f(t,\beta ,\mu , \theta )= e^{\theta(t-\mu)^{\beta}}$ a well known distribution on the unit interval?

Tags: normal-distribution, beta-distribution

$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}$
I have tried out to define a new  distribution lie in [0,1] using my special function which is montioned in [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2018/5146794/), The new special function is defined as:
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{a}{(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx, \tag{01}$$ take $t=\erf(x)$ then $x=\erf^{-1}(t)$ such that $ dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{(\erf^{-1}(t))^2 }dt$ by substitution in $\int_{0}^{a}{(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx$ yield to get : $$\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int_{0}^{b}{(e^{(\erf^{-1}(t))^2-t(\erf^{-1}(t))^2})}dt, \tag{02}$$ using this approximation for small $t$ we have :$\erf^{-1}(t) \sim t\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ , Replace this approixmation gives the following :$$\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int_{0}^{b}{e^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}(t^2-t^3)}}dt .\tag{03}$$
Now for the latter equality I want to define a new distribution since we are now in [0,1], because the precedent variable change $t$ vary from $0$ to $1$ because $ \erf^{-1}(\infty)=1 $, Then let us define a Unit distribution with $3$ parametre : $\beta$ and $\mu$ and $\theta $ such that:
$$ f(t,\beta ,\mu , \theta )=e^{\theta(t-\mu)^{\beta}} \text{and} f(t,\beta ,\mu , \theta )=0,  \text{for}: t >1 \tag{04}$$ , Now my question here is this a known distribution and if it is what is it ?

**Edit:** I have edited parameters for generalisation to be clear

Comment: 1. Your title equation has $t$ on the left hand side and $x$ on the right (as per your equation 04 as well); this will be a problem. Best to stick to one variable if you want it to look like an equality. 2. It's not clear what you mean by "unite" here. Do you intend "univariate" instead?

Comment: Thanks it is a wrong typo  now it fixed

Comment: @Glen I mean by unite the distribution defined on (0,1) like Beta distribution

Comment: Okay, that's not how you say that in English. "distribution on the unit interval" would work but may be too long for the title. You should explain the bounds on the variables explicitly in the question where you define the density such that it's clear you intend the density to be 0 outside that interval

Comment: I've cleaned up the title a little. You will need similar changes in the body text.

Comment: @Glen_b it is Weibull Reliability Function for $  \lambda=1$

Comment: @MartijnWeterings , look for small t and since t lie in $(0,1)$ the titled distribution is the antiderivative of Weibull distribution for $ \theta=-1$ and $\n =1$, The problem i challenge now what about positive $ \theta $?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, Try to derive the titled distribution and look what you will get for theta =-1 ?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings,I meant the derivative  for negative theta  since t lie in (0,1) , the support is (0,1)

Comment: @ derivative ( f(t)) at $\theta =-1$ it's equal $-\beta ( t-\mu)\exp(-(t-\mu)^{\beta})$ , and this present distribution probability of Weibull distribution

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, In anyway am looking about kind of the titled distribution by variation of theta

Comment: Which theta? positive or negative?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, derivative for negative theta with theta =-1, clear ?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, For the body text i have trsnsformed the linked special function to define what distribution it can contribute

Comment: @MartijnWeterings , For special case i take  only theta=-1

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, And also for theta negative the derivative still define Weaibull distribution, Right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97587/discussion-between-martijn-weterings-and-zeraoulia-rafik).

Comment: I corrected the expression for dx/dt, also the substituted expression contained a type. I guess that you also need to change the integral  boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

The distribution seems to be close to a truncated form of the [generalized Gaussian distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution) which has the same formula (except it has support on entire $\mathbb{R}$ and some parameters are in a different place, for instance  $\theta = -1/\alpha^\beta$ )

$$f(x) \propto e^{-(\vert x-\mu \vert /\alpha)^\beta} $$

---

One difference is that the function uses the absolute value of $x-\mu $. But , this might be necessary for your distribution as well. In the cases $\mu>0$ and $\beta \notin \mathbb{Z}$ then you the term $(x-\mu)^\beta$ is a non-integer power of a negative number which is problematic. So I guess that your distribution should use the restriction $\mu<0$ in which case the difference with the absolute sign is not relevant.

Comment: Probably you meant $x \notin (0,1) $ not   $\mu \notin (0,1) $

Comment: The generalized Gaussian distribution has a symmetry around $\mu $. If that symmetry boundary  $\mu $ is within zero and one than it will not coincide with your distribution (which does not have this absolute value).

Comment: look your expoenent and your setting of theta , alpha is always positive skew for generalized Gaussian distribution , then  we can't get a positive theta as the case i want

Comment: @zeraouliarafik could you clarify this in the question that you are looking for solutions in the case of positive theta. In the comments you suggested that you are looking for cases with theta=-1

Comment: I'm ready to add a new question for more clarification

Comment: Also other boundaries for the parameters are not so clear. For instance, how do you deal with $\mu>0$ such that there are $x \in (0,1)$ for which $x-\mu<0$? (Then the power term $(x-\mu)^\beta$ may become a complex number when $\beta$ is not an integer)

Answer (score 1):

$f$, in your formulation, is not a probability density function as it does not integrate to 1 on the interval $t\in(0,1)$ for all values of the parameters. You would need to normalize it, but then the expression would not be that nice as it will depend on the parameters through some special functions (actually the cdf of the Generalized Normal distribution).

One alternative is to use the logit transformation applied to the [Generalized Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution), which leads to

$$f(t;\alpha,\beta,\mu) = {\frac {\beta }{2\alpha \Gamma (1/\beta )}} \frac{1}{t(1-t)}\;e^\left\{-\left(\left\vert\mbox{logit}(t)-\mu \right\vert/\alpha \right)^{\beta }\right\}, $$
$t\in(0,1)$, $\mu\in{\mathbb R}$, $\alpha,\beta>0$.

You can call it the Generalized Logit-Normal distribution, which generalizes the logit normal distribution:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution