# What is the type of this distribution :$f(t,\beta ,\mu , \theta )= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{\theta(t-\mu)^{\beta}},\theta >0$ on unit interval?

Tags: normal-distribution, skewness

This question is related to my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/422707/195381) Which is answered by **Martijn Weterings** showning that is closed to truncated Generalised Gaussian distribution for negative $\theta $  values  , My question here is to know what type of this distribution:$$f(t,\beta ,\mu  )= \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{\theta(t-\mu)^{\beta}}$$ with  $f(t,\beta ,\mu , \theta )=0$ when $t >1$ and $t <0$  .       For  $\theta $   positive  which is related to the case includes my defined special function  [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/422707/195381) where $ \theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

**Note**: I have edited the question adding missed factor without changing the meaning of question

$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}$

Comment: yes, sorry i missed that

Comment: Can you show that that is in fact a proper distribution? I don't think it is.

Comment: what  do u meant by proper distribution ?

Comment: Questions of the form what "is" a particular formula are really just asking whether it can be related to a family of distributions that has been studied before.  This one is related to many distributions in many ways, but perhaps the most straightforward connection is with the [Generalized Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution), of which it is a truncated version.

Comment: @whuber the gamma function has a negative exponent

Comment: You are asking this question again, but with the constrain that theta is positive. Can I conclude from this that the other question was about negative theta? (you had not cleared that up yet in the other question)

Comment: Thank you, @Martijn: I should have posted that comment at the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

A density is "proper" if the area under the curve is 1.

Setting $\theta=1, \beta=1, \mu=0$, the density is readily seen as $f=\exp(t)$

but on the domain of $0<t<1$, $$\int_{0}^1 \exp(t) dt = e-1$$

which is not proper.

It is not a density or distribution unless you think harder about its rules.

Comment: But this could be solved by normalizing the function. I guess that the OP means to use the function $$f(t,\beta ,\mu, \theta ) \propto  e^{\theta(t-\mu)^{\beta}}$$

Comment: Sorry , I missed the sqrt(pi)/2  factor in the definion, i have edited it now

Comment: @MartijnWeterings it's more complicated than that. For instance set $\beta=0.5$ and $\mu=0.5$. The density is imaginary now on 0 to 1.

Comment: Yes for any $\mu>0$ and non-integer $\beta$ it is problematic

Comment: @zeraouliarafik elementary calculus should tell you that normalizing constant would not make this any kind of distribution.